# Add a vectorusing Latex as legends in Matlab

Tags: matlab, legend

In example:Add a vector as legends in Matlab posted Mar 2 '15 at 13:45
I want to use the Latex $\mathcal{n}$
By modifying the line

```
LegendString{k} = sprintf('n = %i',n(k));
```

by

```
LegendString{k} = sprintf('\mathcal{n}= %i',n(k),'Interpreter','latex');
```

But it does not work.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up a few things. `sprintf` only generates a string or actually a vector of characters. Therefore, there is no interpreter for `sprintf`.

The interpreter can only be specified for the function rendering the string. Therefore, your example has to be changed to

```
LegendString{k} = sprintf('$\\mathcal{n}= %i$',n(k));

...

legend(LegendString, 'Interpreter', 'Latex');
```

`legend` is the function interpreting the string, therefore `Latex` has to be specified there. Further, using Latex requires `$` around your string to be interpreted in the mathematical environment.

Also, you need to have `\\` rather than `\` since `sprintf` should not use it as a escape character but just keep it in the string.

Comment: Thanks to @Nemesis for the suggestion, but in the vector legends  instead  of getting $\mathcal{n}$  we obtained  \